# Is there a way to see current progress towards a badge?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page

I would like to see how close I am to the `fanatic` badge. However, I am unaware of any way to view how many days I've visited in this streak. Is there a way to view current progress towards badges, rather than your best attempt at getting a badge? Because certain badges' progress restarts on certain actions, like missing a visit.

So is there any way to view the current progress towards a badge and not just your best shot at getting a badge? If this is not already available then this question would it be possible to implement?

Comment: @TinyGiant It seems to only show your best shot at getting a badge. I've used that to see my best shot. But it does not show my current progress towards that.

Comment: In the case of Fanatic specifically, it will track your current progress. I have verified that it immediately cuts off if you miss a day. In the case of Vox Populi and Suffrage, it appears to hold the last day's voting peak until you vote on the current day, at which point it resets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to your profile page and click on the little gear beside the actively tracked badge.

[image]

Then it will show you a list of all available badges and your progress towards them.

[image]

Select the badge you want to see more information about, then click the selected badge to see your progress on that badge.

[image]