# How to see how much rep I have earned towards a specific tag

Tags: support, tags, reputation

I have looked through my profile and used [this question's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303230/is-there-a-way-to-see-current-progress-towards-a-badge), but I can't seem to find where I can see my reputation progress towards a specific tag. For instance, I want to see how close I am to earning [the gold `javascript` badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/78/javascript). I have also used [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:3567262%20[javascript]) to see my activity for the tag. Is it possible to see the reputation I have earned towards this tag though?

Comment: @Turamarth JUST saw this question. Thanks I will delete.